# How to make Laravel run MQTT listener or subscribe

Tags: laravel, mqtt, laravel-artisan, mosquitto, phpmqtt

Currently I am running using command `php arisan start.listening.mqtt`.
However, it will be killed if no more active on the screen.
So can any one suggest a better way for 2 objective

1. Run the MQTT listener as background process through Laravel code
2. When the server reboot, it is started automatically.

Currenly I am using AWS Ubuntu server to run Mosquitto

Comment: Are you running queue workers already? It is a daemon process similar to an MQTT worker, so you might want to check out [the suggested supervisor configuration in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration).

Comment: In addition to the comment above: basically you'll need to follow the [official guide](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) but put `php arisan start.listening.mqtt` into the `command=` field.